# Magento custom function implementation issues

Tags: php, magento

I want to implement some custom php into the product view page. I have a custom function that I want to pull the dynamic price and output a custom message. Only problem is I do not know how to pull in the price variable. Can this even be done the way I am trying or do I have to take the long route and create the xml layout file, template file, etc.? Here is the code I am wanting to implement. I'm still fairly new to Magento so I'm not sure if this type of implementation is completely the opposite of what I should be doing or not.

```
<?php
    $price=5500;        // <--this is the part I can't figure out. I want the current price here (5500 is just there for testing)

    function showPromoBox($price) {   
        $cashrebate=array(.25,.30,.35);
        $aprterm=array(36,36,36);     
        $couponcode=array("25OFF1500","30OFF3000","35OFF5500");
        $payment="";
        if ($price >=1500 && $price < 3000) {
            $x=0;
        } else if ($price >= 3000 && $price < 5500) {
            $x=1;
        } else if ($price >= 5500) {
            $x=2;
        }
        $payment=($price/$aprterm[$x]);
    ?>      Low monthly Payment of <span class="mopymt">$<?php echo number_format(round($payment,2),2); ?>/mo</span><br />
            based on 0% APR for <span class="aprtrm"><?php echo $aprterm[$x]; ?> months</span><br />
            OR<br />
            <span class="cshreb"><?php echo $cashrebate[$x]*100; ?>%</span> off (a savings of <span class="svngs">$<?php echo $price*$cashrebate[$x]; ?></span>) via cash rebate with coupon code: <span class="cpncode"><?php echo $couponcode[$x]; ?></span>.
    <?php } ?>

    <?php   
        if ($price >= 1500) { ?><div class="promobox"><?php showPromoBox($price);?></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

UDPATED CODE:
I have made the following additions/changes but still not sure exactly how to make this happen:

I have created these two files to "create the module":
/app/code/local/Lynskey/ProductPromoBlock/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config> 
    <modules>
        <Lynskey_ProductPromoBlock>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Lynskey_ProductPromoBlock>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and 
store/app/etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lynskey_ProductPromoBlock>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lynskey_ProductPromoBlock>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I vaguely understand that I need more files to accomplish this properly. I will need a .php "logic" file that will set my class and extend a [price] function (still not sure which function to call to get current price, but I'm guessing it will be Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price from app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php

From there I am not sure what other files I need. Also, once this is done, do I simply make a call to the class in the appropriate template file?

Comment: Where are you trying to put this code - on the product view page? if so, you could use `$_product->getPrice();`.  However, the best route, as you note, would be to put this function into a custom block that extends the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` (or relevant) block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, PhilB. I will start researching how to create this into a custom block/function.

Comment: Not a good practice implementing functions and heavy logic in the phtml files.  You should follow the Magento guidelines for implementing these customizations (it will save you a lot of headaches in the future with upgrades/other developers).

Comment: @PhilB, I've made a few steps but the road is still murky. Can you help any further based on what I have given above?

Comment: @dstiefeljr, [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16829/) gives basic code to extend the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price class. I don't have any Magento specific knowledge, so I can't give you a guide to what exactly you'd need to do to get this working. Basically, you'll want to verify that the method name in your class doesn't match any of the method names of the class that you're extending or it will override the original method.